# Multiple instantiation of class in the same variable

Tags: java, null, garbage-collection

i want to know what would happen to the garbage collection if i did something like this:

```
public class Ball {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int radius;
    // Constructors, getters and setters
}

public class BallClient {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Ball myball = new Ball();
      while(true) {
         myball = new Ball();
      }
   }

}
```

Ignore the infinite loop. Would the multiple instantion of Ball on the same variable generate an overhead on the garbage collection? Is it ok to do this or is it bad programming?

I saw this on a method that is called during the whole duration of an app to render images and i couldn't answer if this would be a bad practice or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would the multiple instantion of Ball on the same variable generate an overhead on the garbage collection?

The GC will have to collect these objects, yes. But that's its job, and it's very efficient (optimized) at collecting short-lived objects.

> Is it ok to do this or is it bad programming?

It is OK. Of course, depending on the actual use case, the actual code, the actual design of the classes, it *could* be a better idea to reuse the same ball. But it's not inherently bad practice to create short-lived objects. In fact, that happens all the time.

Whether you use the same variable or not doesn't change much. But, for the sake of readability and maintainability (not performance, which is rarely the main concern you should worry about), the scope of the variable should be as narrow as possible, and it should probably be declared inside the loop rather than outside.

Comment: I agree, but I'd like to add that reusing objects may easily be a premature optimization and I'd suggest to beginners not to do it. It may also be detrimental to the performance, especially when taken to greater length as object pooling.

Answer (score 2):

Once your application no longer has any references to an object it becomes eligible for garbage collection.  Most collectors use a generational layout with young and old regions of the heap.  Since your objects are small they will be allocated in the Eden space (the young generation is typically divided into Eden and survivor spaces).  This is very efficient as it uses pointer bumping to allocate space (around six instructions, which is far more efficient than a call to malloc).  When the Eden space pointer reaches the end of the available space a minor GC will occur.  Only live objects are copied from Eden to a survivor space so the way you've created your objects will place very little load on the collector.  In effect objects that are collected in a minor GC are collected for free.

As a best practice, I would say that yes, creating very short lived objects is good.  What you want to avoid is creating objects that live just long enough to get promoted into the old gen and then become garbage.  Often increasing the size of the young generation can alleviate this.  In this case, it would not be necessary.